# Group one list of string elements based on another list

Tags: python

I want to group by my_list based on another list keys as follows:

```
my_list = ['apple_2010', 'banana_2010', 'carrot_2010', 'dog_2011', 'eye_2011', 'fig_2011']

keys = ['2010','2010','2010','2011','2011','2011']

for x,y in zip(my_list,keys):

???
```

The expected answer is:

```
answer = [['apple_2010', 'banana_2010', 'carrot_2010'],
 ['dog_2011', 'eye_2011', 'fig_2011']]
```

Comment: I just knew to put in zip, but did not know after that...

Comment: Jump in feet first and give it a try - it own't hurt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> my_list = ['apple_2010', 'banana_2010', 'carrot_2010', 'dog_2011', 'eye_2011', 'fig_2011']
>>> keys = ['2010','2010','2010','2011','2011','2011']
>>> print [[value for value in my_list if key in value] for key in set(keys)]

[['dog_2011', 'eye_2011', 'fig_2011'], ['apple_2010', 'banana_2010', 'carrot_2010']]
```